# Filtering a model on a related model still shows the "filtered out" related objects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

A `SportsClass` has many `Courses`.  I want to be able to only get the courses that are available.

I tried the following:

```
sports_classes = db.session.query(SportsClass).join(Course).filter((SportsClass.description.contains(query))|(SportsClass.name.contains(query)))
sports_classes = sports_classes.filter((Course.bookable == "bookable") | (Course.bookable == "waitingList"))
```

However, the result returned by that query are (converted to json and simplified):

```
[
"description": "description",
    "courses": [
      {
        "name": "Name",
        "bookable": "waitingList",
      },
      {
        "name": "Keine Angaben",
        "bookable": "canceled",
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

Why is the canceled course also in the result set?  How can I get just the available courses for each class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing joining/filtering with loading related objects.  Your current query is filtering `SportsClass` to make sure *at least one* of its courses is `'bookable'` or `'waitingList'`.  However, this doesn't effect what gets loaded by the relationship, that's handled separately from loading the query results.

Instead, you probably want a second relationship that only shows the not-canceled classes.  Then put the contents of that relationship in the JSON output, rather than the "full" relationship.

```
class SportsClass(db.Model):
    # ...

class Course(db.Model):
    # ...
    sports_class_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(SportsClass.id), nullable=False)
    sports_class = db.relationship(SportsClass, backref='courses')

SportsClass.available_courses = db.relationship(
    Course, primaryjoin=db.and_(
        SportsClass.id == Course.sports_class_id,
        Course.bookable != 'canceled'
    ), viewonly=True
)
```

(I'm guessing at your model definitions, but the key part is to define and use that extra relationship to `Course` at the end.)